# IF THEN ELSE statement in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

What is wrong with this code?

```
Data antibiotics; 
    set antibiotics; 
    weight2=(IF weight=999,THEN weight2=.); 
        else weight2 = weight; 
run;`
```

I'm trying to create a new variable for weight that accounts for missing data in SAS

Answer (score 2):

It's invalid code. `if` statements in SAS do not come after the `=` sign.

```
data antibiotics;
    set antibiotics;
    
    if(weight = 9999) then weight2 = .;
        else weight2 = weight;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Excel'ist, the `IFN()` function might be familiar construct to you

```
  weight2 = IFN ( weight=999 , . , weight );
```